# Remove url bar from chromeSafariBrowser in flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I am using ChromeSafariBrowser class of flutter_inappwebview to show the webview which contains videos. I am using this class cause it supports pip and also shows media controls on video play which most of dependencies doesnt provide. Now I want to remove the url bar from the top, how can i achieve it?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance..

[I want to remove the rectangular marked area in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8c55.png)

Following is my sample code

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await widget.browser.open(
            url: "https://player.vimeo.com/api/demo",
            options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
              android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
                addDefaultShareMenuItem: false,    
                enableUrlBarHiding:true,         
                toolbarBackgroundColor: "#000000"
              ),
              ios: IOSSafariOptions(
                barCollapsingEnabled: true,
                preferredBarTintColor: "#000000"
              )
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Text("Open Chrome Safari Browser")
      )
```